# Add input to an existing row in csv in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working in python 3.6 on the following structure:

```
import csv

aircraft = input("Please insert the aircraft type : ")
characteristics = input("Please insert the respective aircraft characteristics: ")

with open("aircraft_list.csv","a",newline="") as output:
    if aircraft not in open("aircraft_list.csv").read():
        wr = csv.writer(output)
        wr.writerow([aircraft + "," + characteristics])
        # with squared brackets since otherwise each letter written as a separate string to the csv, separated by comma
    else:
        for row in enumerate(output):
            data = row.split(",")
            if data[0] == aircraft:
                wr = csv.writer(output)
                wr.writerow([characteristics],1)
```

I want to write the inputs to a csv in the following format:

B737,Boeing,1970, etc

A320,Airbus,EU, etc

As long as the aircraft e.g. B737 entry does yet not exist, it is easy to write it to a csv. However, as soon as the B737 property already exists in the csv, I want to add the characteristics (not the aircraft) to the entry already made for the e.g. B737. The order of the characteristics does not matter.

I want the additional input characteristics to be added to the correct row in my csv. How would I do that?

Since I’m new to coding I tried the basics and combined it with code which I found on Stackoverflow but unfortunately I cannot get it working.

Your help would be great, thank you!

Comment: What you want to do involves direct access to a particular row of the file. But a .csv is a textfile and textfiles are not designed for direct access. It is possible but it is tricky and error-prone. Read the .csv file into memory, make your changes there, and then write out a whole new file. To avoid the hassle of old file versus new file, you might like to look at the module `in-place` (https://pypi.org/project/in-place/).

Comment: Might be easier for you to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) if you are new. You can read in the csv, do all of your actions and at the end use ```df.to_csv('file_name.csv')```. It's easy to check if something already exists in pandas. Or use a dictionary to help enforce uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you @lwileczek for the advice, I think I'll indeed start experimenting with pandas.

Comment: @BoarGules thank you for the help, would you advice to use xml instead of csv? It seems in the xml structure I could add data to a 'parent' 'child' structure in the same way I inteded in the csv. Or does xml have the same access issues?

Comment: @Sebas You can't really do parent/child in a .csv file because it is a flat structure, with a fixed number of columns: if the parent has more than one child, you have little option but to repeat the parent's data on multiple lines, once for each child. Doing it in xml will allow you to structure your data in arbitrary ways. *However,* the data you present in your question is *not* parent/child. For every model of plane (eg B737) you have a fixed number of characteristics. But if you want to start with maker, and from there go to model, and from there to characteristics, that *is* parent/child.

Comment: @BoarGules thank you once more for the explanations!